# Recent CheckIns TFS pro grammatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, tfs

I am new to this TFS thing. I am aware of the API to use for Recent CheckIn which is [Changeset API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#get-list-of-changesets). I am also aware that other post about Recent CheckIn, but they don't fulfil what i want. Since TFS has disabled this Recent CheckIn webpart, i need to rebuild this webpart. So in that case , i need to query all the recent checkin with the Id,comment attribute, shown in below.

Anyone can guide me along?

Your help is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If SharePoint webparts supports that) You may try to use net libs for rest api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples

This is example of top 10 chekins:

```
public IEnumerable<TfvcChangesetRef> ListChangesets() 
{ 
    VssConnection connection = this.Context.Connection; 
    TfvcHttpClient tfvcClient = connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>(); 

    IEnumerable<TfvcChangesetRef> changesets = tfvcClient.GetChangesetsAsync(top: 10).Result; 

    foreach (TfvcChangesetRef changeset in changesets) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("{0} by {1}: {2}", changeset.ChangesetId, changeset.Author.DisplayName, changeset.Comment ?? "<no comment>"); 
    } 

    return changesets; 
}
```

Full example here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/Tfvc/ChangesetsSample.cs

Answer (score 0):

Results of Changeset API are sorted by ID in descending order by default. And there is a parameter `$top` which return the maximum number of results you defined.

So basically, you only need to add `$top` parameter, which will return recent checkins you want. The following example will return the most recent 3 checkins:

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$top=3&api-version={version}
```

After running this api, you'll get a JSON file which contains all information of the checkins, then, you need to parse the information in this json file to a table.